# Burninate tags already

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since we are still in the private beta, I decided to work on some Tag Wikis. There are going to be some that just can't be tags, either because they are too broad (i.e. the [self-employed](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-employed) tag), or they do not describe anything useful that is in common with other questions with the tag. What others should we burninate while we're at it? Feel free to edit this post to add some:

- [requests](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requests)
- [problems](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problems)
- [self-employed](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-employed)

Answer (score 5):

I removed those tags from the questions they were assigned. Tags with no questions are soon removed completely. If you see them pop up again, flag one of the questions for moderator attention. This becomes less of a problem after the private beta, when the rep requirements to create new tags is increased: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation.